# VBA Copy/ Paste Dynamic Rows, frequency dependent on column count

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm a total VBA noob and have been struggling to find a solution to what I'm trying to achieve. I can find the pieces online but can't seem to string them together. Would really appreciate some help!

I have a source file in the following format:

```
+------------+------------+----------+--------+--------+
|    From    |     To     | Job Type | Apples | Orange |
+------------+------------+----------+--------+--------+
| 08/01/2015 | 14/01/2015 | Bought   |      1 |      2 |
| 08/01/2015 | 14/01/2015 | Sold     |      3 |      4 |
| 01/01/2015 | 07/01/2015 | Bought   |      5 |      6 |
| 01/01/2015 | 07/01/2015 | Sold     |      7 |      8 |
+------------+------------+----------+--------+--------+
```

I need a macro to convert it into the following format on another worksheet:

```
+------------+------------+----------+---------+-------+
|    From    |     To     | Job Type | Product | Count |
+------------+------------+----------+---------+-------+
| 08/01/2015 | 14/01/2015 | Bought   | Apples  |     1 |
| 08/01/2015 | 14/01/2015 | Sold     | Apples  |     3 |
| 01/01/2015 | 07/01/2015 | Bought   | Apples  |     5 |
| 01/01/2015 | 07/01/2015 | Sold     | Apples  |     7 |
| 08/01/2015 | 14/01/2015 | Bought   | Oranges |     2 |
| 08/01/2015 | 14/01/2015 | Sold     | Oranges |     4 |
| 01/01/2015 | 07/01/2015 | Bought   | Oranges |     6 |
| 01/01/2015 | 07/01/2015 | Sold     | Oranges |     8 |
+------------+------------+----------+---------+-------+
```

However, the number of rows AND columns is dynamic, for example next week 'Bananas' may also appear as a product AND/ OR there may be more date rows.

So I'm trying to copy the dynamic range of rows with the number of occurences being dependent on the number of columns.

I really hope that makes sense. Any help would really be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Does the below code do the trick? Note, I presumed that the original data is in a worksheet named `Original`, and the Expanded version is in a Worksheet named `Expanded`. I created variable names that are very descriptive to help make my code easier to follow, but please post any follow up questions.

```
Sub MoveData()
    Dim wsOriginal As Worksheet
    Dim wsExpanded As Worksheet
    Dim nLastRowExpanded As Long
    Dim nLastRowOriginal As Long
    Dim nSizeOfCopyRange As Long

    ' Number of columns we are expanding
    Const COLUMNS_TO_MOVE As Integer = 2

    Set wsOriginal = Sheets("Original")
    Set wsExpanded = Sheets("Expanded")

    nLastRowOriginal = wsOriginal.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    nSizeOfCopyRange = nLastRowOriginal - 1

    For i = 1 To COLUMNS_TO_MOVE
        nLastRowExpanded = wsExpanded.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wsOriginal.Range("A2:C" & nLastRowOriginal).Copy wsExpanded.Range("A" & nLastRowExpanded)
        wsExpanded.Range("D" & nLastRowExpanded).Value = wsOriginal.Cells(1, 3 + i).Value
        wsExpanded.Range("D" & nLastRowExpanded).AutoFill Destination:=wsExpanded.Range("D" & nLastRowExpanded).Resize(nSizeOfCopyRange)
        wsOriginal.Range("D2:D" & nLastRowOriginal).Offset(, i - 1).Copy wsExpanded.Range("E" & nLastRowExpanded)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying, got caught up in work and weekend stuff. Thanks VERY much for this, it's definitely half-way there. However, if the source file contains an additional column (for Bananas, for example), then this is not copied onto the 'Expanded' worksheet. I think the 'COLUMNS_TO_MOVE' needs to be a count of all non-blank columns minus the 3 constant columns. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Right, after some tinkering with the above code (thanks again, user3561813), I've got it to do what I need. It's possible some of the below is extraneous, but if it ain't broke...

I attached the action to a button called ' Restructure'

```
Private Sub Restructure_Click()

Worksheets("Original").Activate

Dim wsOriginal As Worksheet
Dim wsExpanded As Worksheet
Dim nLastRowExpanded As Long
Dim nLastRowOriginal As Long
Dim nSizeOfCopyRange As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long

Set wsOriginal = Sheets("Original")
Set wsExpanded = Sheets("Expanded")

lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim DATARANGE As Range
Set DATARANGE = Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(1, lastColumn))

nLastRowOriginal = wsOriginal.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
nSizeOfCopyRange = nLastRowOriginal - 1

For i = 1 To DATARANGE.Count

    nLastRowExpanded = wsExpanded.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
    wsOriginal.Range("A2:C" & nLastRowOriginal).Copy wsExpanded.Range("A" & nLastRowExpanded)
    wsExpanded.Range("D" & nLastRowExpanded).Value = wsOriginal.Cells(1, 3 + i).Value
    wsExpanded.Range("D" & nLastRowExpanded).AutoFill Destination:=wsExpanded.Range("D" & nLastRowExpanded).Resize(nSizeOfCopyRange)
    wsOriginal.Range("D2:D" & nLastRowOriginal).Offset(, i - 1).Copy wsExpanded.Range("E" & nLastRowExpanded)
Next i

End Sub
```